# Java - Multiple users conflict while accessing Word-files

Tags: java, pdf, vbscript, ms-word, conflict

My java application uses a visual basic script to let MS Word convert .docx files to .pdf files in the background. Users can select a product and request the script to return for example a quotation in .pdf format.

A significant requirement is that the vbscript cannot access the documents when they reside within the jar file.

These .docx files are stored on a shared drive, but when multiple users try to generate a quotation with the same .docx file, a conflict obviously occurs.

Should I include the documents in the application and let it export them to say /USER/AppData so every user has their own copy of the documents? Are there any other obvious methods that I am missing out on? Or just go for the workaround where only one quotation can be generated simultaneously?

Comment: One other option is to make sure all your `.docx` files have unique names, a GUID for example.

Comment: What I do is create a properties file. I add would add docCounter = 0; Then in my program every time a user converters a file I would use the current docCounter then increment it. String tempFileName = "path/to/file/tempfile" + retrieveProperty("docCounter") + ".docx"; If you use Netbeans to create a new project with the default name, you will see this behavior.